# Removing special characters from URL column in a database table

Tags: sql, url, mysql-workbench, urldecode

I have a table in which a column has URLS with special characters.
For example I have characters like these ä è æ µ.
Is there a way where I can remove the characters or append the url with any understandable decoding?
¨

Comment: Please post the DDL (aka the `create table` statement).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0 you have the new function `regexp_replace`. For example, you can use it to remove digits below:

```
select regexp_replace('The licence plate is A6Z4J1', '^[a-zA-Z]', '');
-- The licence plate is AZJ
```

If you are using MySQL before version 8.0 you will need to create a procedure to do this.